# Unable to show popup first time after 20 sec in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, popup

**code:** here `norecordView` is custom popup view. I have created popup, which i need to show after 20 sec of the app open but here only print statement is showing after 20sec but popup is not coming, for first time, why? if i close and open again then after 20sec popup showing. please guide me

```
class DashboardVC: UIViewController {

var norecordView = NoRecordView()
var timer = Timer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.startAlertTimer), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc func startAlertTimer()
{
    print("start 20 sec timer")
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.showPopup), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
@objc func showPopup()
{
    print("after 20 sec")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    norecordView = NoRecordView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    norecordView.blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.8)
    self.view.addSubview(norecordView)
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is `showPopup()` called in main thread? Do you have errors log saying that some UI should be made in main thread?

Comment: @Larme, i have edited my post.. but popup not showing first time.. but if i close and open again then popup coming after 20sec, why first time not coming.. where am i wrong.. please guide me

Comment: Not related but you add a new instance of NoRecordView to your view hierarchy, not removing any previous ones, so you're going to end up with multiple NoRecordViews.  You set the frame of the NoRecordView but do nothing to lay it out either automatically or manually when your view's bounds changes

Comment: You also new up instances of Timer and NoRecordView in your properties which you don't need, just make them optional. And you don't assign to self.timer in startAlertTimer()

Comment: @Shadowrun, i have followed your suggestion.. but still facing the same problem.. please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502671/why-popup-view-not-showing-1st-time-when-app-in-foreground-state-in-swift

Comment: @Shadowrun, how to remove popview completely from dashboard viewcontroller when i close popup... ?.. please guide

Answer (score 0):

```swift
import UIKit

class DashboardVC: UIViewController {

    var norecordView = UIView()
    var timer = Timer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        norecordView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 500)
        norecordView.isHidden = true
        norecordView.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(norecordView)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.startAlertTimer), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    }


    @objc func startAlertTimer()
    {
        print("start 5 sec timer")
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.showPopup), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }



    @objc func showPopup()
    {
        print("after 5 sec")
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in

//            norecordView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

            norecordView.isHidden = false

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i add `norecordView.isHidden = true` and `self.view.addSubview(norecordView)` in didload then only first time coming not every time when app is in foreground state

Comment: could you edit your answer with all times app show popup